# How to remove trailing spaces \n but not trailing tabs \t

Tags: groovy, tabs, spaces

I have strings in Groovy in a tsv file. The values are always strings. In the final column, the strings may sometimes have trailing spaces.

I normally remove these spaces with `.trim(), e.g.

```
stringHere = 'example   '
print(stringHere.trim())
```

The problem I've noticed with `.trim()` is that it appears to remove trailing tabs as well.

Is there a method that would only remove `\n` and not `\t`?

Comment: `stringHere.replaceAll( /\n+$/, '' )`

Comment: @daggett Wouldn't that replace spaces within strings as well?

Comment: No, that's only for `\n`. To make regexp for space, `\n`, `\r` : `stringHere.replaceAll( /[ \n\r]+$/, '' )`

Comment: @daggett Sorry for the delay. Could you provide a solution? Or would you recommend I delete the question?

Comment: `\n` represents a new line. do you want to remove new lines or spaces?

Comment: @daggett Actually, I'm confused. I only want to remove spaces, but you are saying that `\n` is a new line. Isn't that a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def stringHere = '12345\t   '
//remove spaces only
stringHere = stringHere.replaceAll(/ +$/,'')
println "stringHere = `${stringHere}`"
//let's check
assert stringHere.length()==6
assert stringHere.charAt(5)=='\t'
```